# Calling the Javascript Function once the table is loaded dynamically using ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

I want to call a Javascript function once the table is done loading.

I thought of using onload() function on table, but later I came to know that onload() doesnt work for table.

Comment: You can call function in the `success` or `complete` callback of AJAX

Comment: Could you add some code

Comment: please show us some code..
You can call your desired function in success function of ajax call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using ajax call to load the data in table, after that you can call the javascript function inside the success .

```
 $.ajax(
    {
        type: "GET",
        url: "yoururl",
        data: "yourdata",

        success: function(tableData)
        {   
             // load the table using data
            //Call the function you want to call 
             myJavascriptFunction();
        }
    });
```